# Enquete com PHP

Tags: php

10 usuários responderão uma enquete com 19 opções iguais para todos, cada resposta é salva no banco numa tabela chamada 'votos' com a seguinte estrutura:
id: 1 - user_id: 1 - resposta: {resposta do usuário}

Quero contabilizar todas as 10 respostas e mostrar a mais votada, por exemplo.
3 pessoas votaram na opção 'CASA'.
5 pessoas votaram na opção 'TRABALHO'
e 2 pessoas votaram na opção 'LAZER'.

Como posso mostrar que a mais votada foi TRABALHO e que 5 pessoas votaram nela?

Comment: se o campo resposta for do tipo varchar pode ser que vc tenha problemas, mas acredito que tudo que você precisar fazer é um count no campo resposta e agrupar por usuário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Se entendi direito sua pergunta ...**

**e se a tabela é assim .....**

[image: tabela]

**então o select é esse**

```
Select resposta, count(resposta)
from votos
group by resposta
having count(resposta)=(Select max(A.CNT)
from (Select count(resposta) as CNT
from votos
group by (resposta)) as A)
```

**e o resultado é esse**

[image: resultado]

Comment: Funciona. Mas não entendi nada kkkkkk.

Comment: @VitorLeite, pois é, tem que dar uma pesquisada/estudada em cada clausula da query pra vc entender, count, group, having. Agora se a resposta serviu marque-a como aceita.